# Append data from first MySQL table to second by ID

Tags: mysql

I have two MySql Databases. 
One has:

```
___id___|___name___|__date____|
```

Second database has

```
___id___|___tag___|
```

One common thing in this tables - `id`. It's same in both tables. How can i append column `"tag"` to first mysql database?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just want a view of the columns in the first table along with a possible matching tag, then use a query:

```
SELECT
    t1.id, t1.name, t1.date, t2.tag
FROM table1 t1
LEFT JOIN table2 t2
    ON t1.id = t2.id;
```

If you instead want to actually *add* a new tag column to the first table, then add that column and then do an update:

```
ALTER TABLE table1 ADD COLUMN tag VARCHAR(55);

UPDATE table1 t1
INNER JOIN table2 t2
    ON t1.id = t2.id
SET t1.tag = t2.tag;
```

Comment: Yes, second option. 
What is t1 and t2 in your example?

Comment: @Rost `t1` and `t2` are just aliases to your first and second table (in the order you described in your original question).